# Why does introducing this existential quantifier cause non-termination?

Tags: z3, smt, theorem-proving

I am just starting to play with Z3 on my own and I thought one interesting experiment would be to construct a 3-element field.

So I declared my field S to be a scalar enumeration of three elements, A, B, C, and started gradually adding field axioms, asking Z3 for a model after each step, just to see what is going on.  All goes well until I assert the possibility of subtraction, ∀ab.(∃x.a+x=b):

```
(declare-datatypes () ((S A B C)))

; there exist three distinct elements in S
(declare-const someA S)
(declare-const someB S)
(declare-const someC S)
(assert (distinct someA someB someC))

(declare-fun ADD (S S) S)
(declare-fun MUL (S S) S)

; commutative
(assert (forall ((x S) (y S)) (= (ADD x y) (ADD y x))))
(assert (forall ((x S) (y S)) (= (MUL x y) (MUL y x))))

; associative
(assert (forall ((x S) (y S) (z S)) (= (ADD x (ADD y z)) (ADD (ADD x y) z))))
(assert (forall ((x S) (y S) (z S)) (= (MUL x (MUL y z)) (MUL (MUL x y) z))))

; subtractivity
(assert (forall ((a S) (b S)) (exists ((x S)) (= (ADD a x) b))))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

This results in Z3 looping forever.  I am surprised.  I mean yes, I understand why FOL is in general undecidable, but I'd think this would be one of those "easy" cases because the space of all possible values for a, b and ADD is finite (and in this case even very small)?  Why does it loop?  and what is the correct way to express the subtractability axiom preferably in a way that doesn't lose being perceivable as its intended intuitive meaning?

Comment: Quantifiers are hard, alternating quantifiers are harder. While you've a finite (and small) domain, z3 is failing to recognize that and most likely getting swamped in the guts of the e-matcher. These sorts of problems are just not suitable for SMT-solving: I'd recommend using a proper theorem prover (like Isabelle, Coq, Agda, HOL, Lean, etc.) for dealing with these sorts of axiomatizations.

Answer (score 0):

While @alias is generally right with his suggestion, you might nevertheless be able to use Z3 if you're willing to weaken your axiomatisation. E.g.:

```
...
; subtractivity
(declare-fun SUB (S S) S)
(assert (forall ((a S) (b S) (x S)) (iff (= (ADD a x) b) (= (SUB b x) a))))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```